Looking for DataSet on Predicting Psychosomatic Disorders Arising from Intensive Exposure to Social Networks
I'm conducting research on the prediction of psychosomatic disorders stemming from intensive exposure to social networks. I'm in need of a dataset to analyze and model this phenomenon. Could you please recommend any specific sources or databases where I can find a dataset containing relevant data on social media usage patterns, psychological indicators, and potential psychosomatic symptoms? Ideally, the dataset would include variables such as time spent on social media platforms, types of interactions, self-reported mental health metrics, and any diagnosed psychosomatic disorders. Your assistance in locating such a dataset would be greatly appreciated
im looking for dataset for training

Recommendation questions are off-topic here, and also, what does this have to do with programming?

@Dr.Snoopy I appreciate your feedback. I'm conducting machine learning research focused on predicting psychosomatic disorders resulting from intensive exposure to social networks. For my analysis and modeling, I need a dataset that includes variables such as:
Time spent on social media platforms
Types of interactions (e.g., likes, comments, shares)
Self-reported mental health metrics
Diagnosed psychosomatic disorders
This dataset is crucial for training machine learning models to identify patterns and make accurate predictions.

The feedback is "you are not going to get recommendations for a dataset here", please read what people actually say. You seem to assume that Machine Learning implies programming, but it does not.
